# Changing TF300 keyboard dock to Icelandic

Tags: keyboard, languages, docking-station

I have a Asus TF300 keyboard dock that has an American-style qwerty layout. Is it possible to change it to Icelandic, so that I can type in Icelandic letters from the keyboard dock?

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

Try [External Keyboard Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper).

> A non visible soft keyboard (Input Method) intended to be used with hardware Bluetooth and USB keyboards. It automatically brings up the Input Method dialog when Bluetooth keyboard connects or disconnects (on some devices this can also be made to work with USB keyboards). It supports a lot of different keylayouts also provides a lot of configuration options.